# Returning a hash instead of array with ActiveRecord::Base.connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to use a query like this :

```
query = Enc.joins(:rec).group("enc.bottle").
select("enc.bottle as mode, count(rec.id) as numrec, sum(enc.value) as sumvalue")
```

That I use with :

```
@enc = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(query)
```

To get the data, I've to do `@enc.rows.first[0]` (it works)

But `@enc.rows.first["mode"]` doesn't work ! Because each row of `@enc.rows` contains array.. not a map with the name of each field.

Maybe `select_all` is a wrong method.

Does it exist another method to get the data with the name of field ?

Thank you

**EDIT**

[image: Description]

Comment: Could you post the complete error message you get when using AR?

Comment: I've tried similar queries on a rails app running 3.2.18 with a MySQL database, and it works just like you are requesting. What version of Rails are you using and which database?

Comment: I have the latest version of rails. `@enc.rows.first[0]` works but not `@enc.rows.first["mode"]`. I'm going to edit my post with a screenshot of Rubymine debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can associate a model with the query, then there's no need for the generic `select_all` method. You can use `find_by_sql` like this:

```
Enc.find_by_sql(query).first.mode
# => testing
```

Note that you will no be able to see the aliases when inspecting the results, but they are there. Also, the convention is to use plural names for the tables. You might find it easier to just sticks with the defaults.

Comment: I've added an image... My DB isn't rails standard. I don't have a HASH... Just a array with column names and another array with values..